# Set default value of model property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to set default value of a model property with Typescript.

I tried like this using getter and setters but it doesn't changed:

```
export class Definition extends BaseModel{
    id: number;
    parent_id:number;
    name: string;
    parent_name: string;
    active:boolean;
    get active_text(): string {
        return this.active ? 'Aktif':'Pasif';
    }
    set active_text(value:string) {
        this.active_text = value;
    }

}
```

I want to set `active_text` a string by `active` propery value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Things would maybe be clearer and more easily implemented with a backing field to your `active_text` property :

```
export class Definition extends BaseModel{
    // ... other fields here 

    _active_text: string;
    get active_text(): string {
        // Use this._active_text value unless it is falsy (empty or undefined),
        // in this case use calulated value
        return this._active_text || (this._active ? 'Aktif':'Pasif');
    }
    set active_text(value:string) {
        this._active_text = value;
    }

}
```

EDIT : another strategy, depending on your usage, would be to trigger the change in `active_text` when you set the `active` value, for instance :

```
active_text: string;

_active: boolean;
get active(): boolean{
    return this._active;
}
set active(value: boolean) {
    this._active = value;
    if (!this.active_text) { // the 'if' is here to prevent overriding an existing value)
        this.active_text = this._active ? 'Aktif': 'Pasif'; 
    }
}
```

The initial values could also be set in the definition or in a constructor, as already noted in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,

```
    export class test
    {
    constructor()
    {}

    id: number;
    parent_id:number;
    name: string;
    parent_name: string;
    private  _activeText:string;
    get activeText(): string
    {
        return this._activeText ? 'Aktif':'Pasif';
    }
    set activeText(value:string)
    {
        this._activeText = value;

    }

}
 const  t = new test();
 t.activeText = "value";
console.log(t.activeText);
```

Comment: you are setting a value outside of class.

Comment: That is how getters and setter work right or should be used ? check here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: You should set the active then activeText will be calculated. You set wrong property.Make a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to initialize the value?

```
export class Definition extends BaseModel{
    id: number = 1;
    parent_id:number;
    name: string;
    parent_name: string;
    active:boolean;
    get active_text(): string {
        return this.active ? 'Aktif':'Pasif';
    }
    set active_text(value:string) {
        this.active_text = value;
    }

}
```

If you want a default value per instance intialize it via the the constructor

```
export class Definition extends BaseModel{
    parent_id:number;
    name: string;
    parent_name: string;
    active:boolean;

    constructor(private id: number) {
    }
    get active_text(): string {
        return this.active ? 'Aktif':'Pasif';
    }
    set active_text(value:string) {
        this.active_text = value;
    }

}
```

Also notice that you are using your getter to set the value, which will not work;

```
set active_text(value:string) {
        this.active = value;
    }
```